# Reading and selecting items from a csv file with different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to get some items from a csv file but there's a problem, it has different number of columns so I can not use the pandas.read_csv(filepath) function to read it. I need to open it so that I can then select some of the items that are shown. The csv file is the following (with an added blank line between each row so that it is easier for you all to read):

"Path","File","Date Acquired","Sample","Misc"

"C:\msdchem\2\DATA\AlbertVirgili\DaniGM\","DGM_CPTIS003 1h.D","25-Mar-19, 
11:55:48","DGM_CPTIS003 1h"," "

"INT FID1A.CH"

"Mon Mar 25 17:48:31 2019"

"Peak","R.T.","Start","End","PK TY","Height","Area","Pct Max","Pct Total"

1,  2.082,  2.063,  2.189,"BB  ",223849319,4951058782,100.00, 46.349

2,  2.317,  2.281,  2.386,"BB  ",73209942,1093871144, 22.09, 10.240

3,  3.343,  3.224,  3.403,"BB  ",93165657,2220621038, 44.85, 20.788

4,  5.538,  5.409,  5.598,"BB  ",51783798,1975386485, 39.90, 18.492

5,  5.744,  5.693,  5.803,"BB  ",24084957,360235490,  7.28,  3.372

6,  8.716,  8.676,  8.776,"BB  ",8566883, 80973220,  1.64,  0.758

"Path","File","Date Acquired","Sample","Misc"

"C:\msdchem\2\DATA\AlbertVirgili\DaniGM\","DGM_CPTIS003 2h.D","25-Mar-19, 12:15:42","DGM_CPTIS003 2h"," "

"INT FID1A.CH"

"Mon Mar 25 12:31:45 2019"

"Peak","R.T.","Start","End","PK TY","Height","Area","Pct Max","Pct Total"

1,  2.083,  2.064,  2.194,"BB  ",232382153,5255486688,100.00, 59.673

2,  2.318,  2.282,  2.384,"BB  ",37916041,587535474, 11.18,  6.671

3,  3.322,  3.241,  3.381,"BB  ",67715293,1373898201, 26.14, 15.600

4,  5.509,  5.406,  5.569,"BB  ",39502747,1227609422, 23.36, 13.939

5,  5.731,  5.689,  5.791,"BB  ",17799521,230201751,  4.38,  2.614

6,  8.717,  8.674,  8.776,"BB  ",12367646,132409300,  2.52,  1.503

What I need to do is read the items that are under the Headers: Peak, R.T., Start, End, PK TY,... but I can not do that because of their different lenght with the previous lines (with headers Path, File, Date Acquired...). I can not use the skiprows function to just eliminate the lines from 0-3 and 11-14 because the number of rows of the part that I want to read is not always consistent (this type of files are generated by an external program and I can not modify its structure). Is there any way that I can use to read only the part of the csv code that falls under my desired headers so that I can use it to select the desired data from those values?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Read it in using the standard python libraries. Find the areas to split and the specific skip-rows functions. Then, using `StringIO` read each CSV in separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some preprocessing. Thinking about these integration points is very common if you work with data from external systems.

The external file contains structured data. A sequence of CSV lines, each item has 5 header rows. The last header row contains the CSV column labels.

Read in content from external file. Adapt the code below to your needs.

```
external_file_content = r'''
"Path","File","Date Acquired","Sample","Misc"
"C:\msdchem\2\DATA\AlbertVirgili\DaniGM\","DGM_CPTIS003 1h.D","25-Mar-19, 11:55:48","DGM_CPTIS003 1h"," "
"INT FID1A.CH"
"Mon Mar 25 17:48:31 2019"
"Peak","R.T.","Start","End","PK TY","Height","Area","Pct Max","Pct Total"
1, 2.082, 2.063, 2.189,"BB ",223849319,4951058782,100.00, 46.349
2, 2.317, 2.281, 2.386,"BB ",73209942,1093871144, 22.09, 10.240
3, 3.343, 3.224, 3.403,"BB ",93165657,2220621038, 44.85, 20.788
4, 5.538, 5.409, 5.598,"BB ",51783798,1975386485, 39.90, 18.492
5, 5.744, 5.693, 5.803,"BB ",24084957,360235490, 7.28, 3.372
6, 8.716, 8.676, 8.776,"BB ",8566883, 80973220, 1.64, 0.758
"Path","File","Date Acquired","Sample","Misc"
"C:\msdchem\2\DATA\AlbertVirgili\DaniGM\","DGM_CPTIS003 2h.D","25-Mar-19, 12:15:42","DGM_CPTIS003 2h"," "
"INT FID1A.CH"
"Mon Mar 25 12:31:45 2019"
"Peak","R.T.","Start","End","PK TY","Height","Area","Pct Max","Pct Total"
1, 2.083, 2.064, 2.194,"BB ",232382153,5255486688,100.00, 59.673
2, 2.318, 2.282, 2.384,"BB ",37916041,587535474, 11.18, 6.671
3, 3.322, 3.241, 3.381,"BB ",67715293,1373898201, 26.14, 15.600
4, 5.509, 5.406, 5.569,"BB ",39502747,1227609422, 23.36, 13.939
5, 5.731, 5.689, 5.791,"BB ",17799521,230201751, 4.38, 2.614
6, 8.717, 8.674, 8.776,"BB ",12367646,132409300, 2.52, 1.503
'''
```

Split sequence into unique parts using a well-defined separator

```
parts = external_file_content.split('"Path","File","Date Acquired","Sample","Misc"')
```

Select a single part for further processing into a pandas DataFrame. Configure `pd.read_csv` to skip 4 rows.

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(parts[1]), skiprows=4);
```

Show first rows of DataFrame

```
df.head(5)


    Peak    R.T.    Start   End     PK TY   Height  Area    Pct Max     Pct Total
0   1   2.082   2.063   2.189   BB  223849319   4951058782  100.00  46.349
1   2   2.317   2.281   2.386   BB  73209942    1093871144  22.09   10.240
2   3   3.343   3.224   3.403   BB  93165657    2220621038  44.85   20.788
3   4   5.538   5.409   5.598   BB  51783798    1975386485  39.90   18.492
4   5   5.744   5.693   5.803   BB  24084957    360235490   7.28    3.372
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice. How should I get the initial data from the csv file then so that I can apply the split function? By getting the rows using with open (filepath) as csvFile and getting the rows from there?

Comment: Reading files with Python is a well covered topic in the internet. "Trial and error" is a powerful way for exploration and learning.

Answer (score 1):

Filter out non-numeric rows

```
def gen_rows(stream):
    for row in csv.reader(stream):             
        if row.pop(0).isdigit(): # check that value is a number  
            yield row

with open('data.csv') as fo:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(gen_rows(fo), 
    columns = ["Peak","R.T.","Start","End","PKTY",
                    "Height","Area","Pct Max","Pct Total"])
```